# django: Using dictionaries as values for models.Choices

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to save a frequency to the database, which consists of an amount (e.g. 2) and a unit (e.g. months). The user must be given a choice, too. The idea is to pass this to a class that can use this info to calculate frequency (similar to, but not quite `timedelta`, however this is beyond the scope of this question).

I thought it would be neat if I could save this information as a dict into a JSONField, and when retrieving it programmatically, I could pass it straight onto my `CustomFrequencyClass` in charge of the calculations.

The error I invariably get is `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. Or, if I pass the values as tuples, it'll tell me `(fields.E005) 'choices' must be an iterable containing (actual value, human readable name) tuples.`

```py
class CustomFrequencyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass

class Report(models.Model):
    class ReportFrequency(CustomFrequencyClass, models.Choices):
        DAILY = {"days": 1}, "Daily"
        WEEKLY = {"days": 7}, "Weekly"

    frequency = models.JSONField(choices=ReportFrequency.choices, default=ReportFrequency.DAILY)
```

Comment: Why do you create a `CustomFrequencyClass`?

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem because `timedelta` doesn't work with `months` (where I only increment the month). But the question is meant more generically - how to pass dictionaries as choice values.

Comment: You can use a `relativedelta(...)`: https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html#module-dateutil.relativedelta

Comment: @willeM_VanOnsem yes, thanks but that 1/ requires an extra dependency and 2/ doesn't address the question above (which is about passing dictionaries as choice values).

Comment: well another dependency would be to work with `frozendict` :)

Answer (score 0):

If you work with [**`choices=…`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#choices), Django will construct a dictionary behind the curtains to map the values to the text representation, so in this case `{'days': 1}` to `'Daily'`, since the keys of a dictionary need to be hashable, and a dictionary can not be hashable since it can be modified, it thus does not work.

We can however wrap the dictionary in a [**`frozendict`** <sup>[pypi.org]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/frozendict/), which make it possible to hash it, but of course under the promise that the dictionary is then not updated anymore.

```
from frozendict import frozendict


class Report(models.Model):
    class ReportFrequency(models.Choices):
        DAILY = frozendict({'days': 1}), 'Daily'
        WEEKLY = frozendict({'days': 7}), 'Weekly'

    frequency = models.JSONField(
        choices=ReportFrequency.choices, default=ReportFrequency.DAILY
    )
```